# The anti-forgery token could not be decrypted & The anti-forgery cookie token and form field token do not match in deployment

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have this issue in my deployment server **sometimes** and it's driving me nuts because I can't reproduce in the localhost, I've tried adding machine key in my web.config but no luck so far.

It only happened in login page.

My Layout :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body>
    <form id="__AjaxAntiForgeryForm" action="#" method="post">
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    </form>

    <div class="wcenter">
        @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
    </div>

    <br />

    <div class="wcenter">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/pluginjs")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/customjs")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

My Login Page

```
@model LoginViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Log in";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Username)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Username)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Username)

                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)

                <input type="submit" value="LOGIN" />
            }
```

Controller :

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Username, Id = model.Username };
        var result = await UserManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, model.Password);

        if (result == true)
        {
            if (UserManager.FindByName(user.UserName) == null)
            {
                var res = UserManager.Create(user);

                if (!res.Succeeded)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", res.Errors.FirstOrDefault());
                    return View(model);
                }
            }

            SignInManager.SignIn(user, true, true);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
        return View(model);
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Strange behaviour....Can you run the network trace to check if __RequestAnitForgeryToken passed in Request's form parameter is same as generated in your html Login form?

Comment: Okay so I did a little test and found out it only happened if I login then wait a while until it timeout and try to login again, that way I will always get the error `The anti-forgery cookie token and form field token do not match.`.

Comment: I think your problem is **@Html.AntiForgeryToken()** in your layout page. As far as I know you should include this helper inside forms that you use to post data back to the server. In your layout page there is an empty form.

Comment: @warheat1990 - Seems that even in timeout, server authenticates the user and updated Identity.IsAuthenticated to true so on next time, since, initial anitforgery token was issued to anonymous user will not be validated by server.

Answer (score 2):

Its because you are creating 2 Antiforgery token, one inside the form, and the other in your partial view. So sometimes the cookie CSRF created do not match with the CSRF input hidden field

Comment: So what can I do to fix this issue? I need the 2nd token for my ajax call.

Comment: You must keep only one reference to @Html.AntiForgeryToken(), for your ajax call, you can search for the token, and put in your header's request. Ex: var csrfToken = $('body').find('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();